# JavaFX ScrollPane and FlowPane properties to resize the FlowPane if columns overfill the ScrollPane width

Tags: javafx, scrollpane, flowpane

I have a `FlowPane` wrapped in a `ScrollPane`. `FlowPane` orientation is `Vertical`, so it will wrap the controls. But I want to set the `FlowPane` to resize vertically if the columns size is greater than the width of `ScrollPane`. I've tried a lot of settings, both on `ScrollPane` and `FlowPane` but none of them helped me with my wish.
As an image of how I want to do is something like this:
(red contur is `ScrollPane`, green is `FlowPane`)

Containers, after the flow pane is populated, with `ScrollPane`'s width more than two columns of controls:
[image: populated]

How it works right now, after resizing:

[image]

How I want to do after resizing the `ScrollPane`:

[image: after_resizing]

Can this be achieved? What settings I must do to both `ScrollPane` and `FlowPane`?

---

**Edit:**

Minimal reproduction code:

hello-view.fxml:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="424.0" prefWidth="457.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.demo.HelloController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="399.0" prefWidth="430.0" style="-fx-border-color: #555555;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0">
         <children>
            <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" focusTraversable="false" hbarPolicy="NEVER" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="13.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="377.0" prefWidth="404.0" style="-fx-border-color: red; -fx-border-width: 2;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="7.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="13.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="12.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="12.0">
               <content>
                  <FlowPane maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="363.0" prefWidth="397.0" rowValignment="TOP" style="-fx-border-color: green; -fx-border-width: 2;">
                     <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="121.0" prefWidth="140.0" text="1">
                           <FlowPane.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
                           </FlowPane.margin>
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                        <Button layoutX="12.0" layoutY="12.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="121.0" prefWidth="140.0" text="2">
                           <FlowPane.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
                           </FlowPane.margin>
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                        <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="135.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="121.0" prefWidth="140.0" text="3">
                           <FlowPane.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
                           </FlowPane.margin>
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                        <Button layoutX="154.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="121.0" prefWidth="140.0" text="4">
                           <FlowPane.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
                           </FlowPane.margin>
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                  </FlowPane>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

HelloController.java:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to JavaFX Application!");
    }
}
```

HelloApplication.java

```java
package com.example.demo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

`HelloApplication.java` and `HelloController.java` are default demo files from starting project in JavaFX.

Conclusion:
Is there a combination of properties for `ScrollPane` and `FlowPane` to be able to resize the `FlowPane` vertically and stop resizing in the right when the control inside tries to move to create a new column (this happens when `ScrollPane` resize vertically)? I don't want to create those invisible columns in the right, instead grows the FlowPane vertically!
Mention: this could happens in two way

1. when resize form from the bottom, and the controls from the bottom of the `FlowPane` will move to the top, and the `FlowPane` will resize automatically to the right and put the controls in the hidden area of `FlowPane`, (and)
2. When you resize form horizontally and there is no more space to move the controls from the right column to the next row, so the `FlowPane` will not stay anchored to right and to try to create an "invisible" row (or as many as it takes to move needed controls down).

I hope I make it clear as possible.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Ok, I will try to substract  this problem from my app and I will edit soon the question, sorry for that.

Comment: I've added the minimal code for reproduction

Comment: Your problem (or one of them) is the [orientation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html#orientationProperty) property of the FlowPane, which you have set to VERTICAL, which means "A vertical flowpane lays out children top to bottom, wrapping at the flowpane's height.", but the height has no meaning because it is in a scrollpane.  Instead it will wrap based on [prefWrapLength](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html#prefWrapLengthProperty), set that to infinity and it will never wrap.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you might need to create a custom layout pane (i.e. write your layout extending Pane or Region) to achieve the exactly the layout behaviour you want.

Comment: Off topic, but try not to use so many hard-coded values (pref width/height) and manual layout like AnchorPane.  For instance your sample layout could be create using StackPanes with inset padding rather than AnchorPanes with hardcoded sizes, layout co-ordinates and anchors.

Comment: Thanks @jewelsea, yes indeed, seems to be a weird orientation, but I've saw this tyof orientation in a software made by a mondial hardware/software brand. It's weird, but in the same time it has a logic regarding to parent's ScrollBars visibility. Think about it, if the horizontal scrollbar is set to `Never`, but user wants to fill the `FlowPane` in vertical orientation (like in my situation), then there is no logic to resize the `FlowPane` to the right. In the next comment I'll post how I've did it finally, but it works only for my case, with same controls size.

Comment: I've wrapped the `FlowPane` in an `AnchorPane` and I've set it to anchor to all locations (top, bottom, left and right). The `AnchorPane` then is wrapped in the `ScrollPane`. I've added Listners to `ScrollPane`'s widthProperty and heightProperty and calculate the height of the AnchorPane depending on number of controls of FlowPane and how many columns and row could be creating on scrollpane widht.
I don't know if I have to post this as an answer as long as this is limited to same size controls in `FlowPane`.

Comment: You don’t have to post answer, but you could, it [is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  I do think this is a case where a custom layout pane would be preferred, but that is tricky if you have never done it before and there is no official documentation on how to do it.  The approach you have taken while maybe not optimal, seems reasonable.

Comment: hmm .. not near my IDE right now, will try later, but for now a couple of comments: the most important __never-ever__ hard-code sizing constraints, doing so will effectively prevent a layout from doing its job (no calculations at all) plus a thingy I don't quite understand:  fitTo for both width and height: doesn't that disable the scrollbars always?

Comment: No @kleopatra, even if fitWidth and fitHeight are set, the `FlowPane` will resize if the content does not fit with the current orientation and bounds. Make test to see it is like that :)

Answer (score -1):

This answer I found it myself and it works only for `FlowPane` containing controls with the same size.

**Purpose:**
Allow user to populate a `FlowPane` in `Vertical` orientation, with parent `ScrollPane`'s scrollbars set only to vertical scrollbar visible (when needed) and the `FlowPane` width to fit `ScrollPane`'s width always.

Starting from a demo project in JavaFX, this is the fxml file which contains definition for the main-view (hello-view.fxml in this case).

`hello-view.fxml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="424.0" prefWidth="457.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.demo.HelloController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="399.0" prefWidth="430.0" style="-fx-border-color: #555555;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0">
         <children>
            <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" fitToWidth="true" focusTraversable="false" hbarPolicy="NEVER" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="13.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="377.0" prefWidth="404.0" style="-fx-border-color: red; -fx-border-width: 0;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="7.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="13.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="12.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="12.0">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane fx:id="ancFlow">
                     <children>
                        <FlowPane fx:id="flowPane" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="368.0" prefWidth="396.0" prefWrapLength="10.0" rowValignment="TOP" style="-fx-border-color: green; -fx-border-width: 0;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                           <children>
                              <Button maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="121.0" prefWidth="140.0" text="1">
                                 <FlowPane.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
                                 </FlowPane.margin>
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="12.0" layoutY="12.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="121.0" prefWidth="140.0" text="2">
                                 <FlowPane.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
                                 </FlowPane.margin>
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="135.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="121.0" prefWidth="140.0" text="3">
                                 <FlowPane.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
                                 </FlowPane.margin>
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                              <Button layoutX="154.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="121.0" prefWidth="140.0" text="4">
                                 <FlowPane.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
                                 </FlowPane.margin>
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Button>
                           </children>
                        </FlowPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

`HelloController.java` file:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class HelloController implements Initializable {
    private final long buttonWidth = 144;
    private final long buttonHeight = 125;
    private double columns;
    private double rows;
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane ancFlow;

    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scrollPane;

    @FXML
    private FlowPane flowPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        // next line was used to see how ancPane is resizing
        //ancFlow.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.rgb(220, 120, 120), new CornerRadii(0), new Insets(0))));
    }

    public void resizeFlowPaneParent(){
        scrollPane.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                if(scrollPane.getHeight() < buttonHeight) return;
                double verticalPadding = scrollPane.getPadding().getTop() + scrollPane.getPadding().getTop();
                ancFlow.setPrefWidth(scrollPane.getWidth() - (scrollPane.getWidth() - scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth()));
                int controls = flowPane.getChildren().size();
                rows = Math.floorDiv(newValue.longValue() , buttonHeight + (long)verticalPadding);
                if((long)rows == 0) return;
                columns = Math.ceilDiv(controls, (long)(rows));
                double matchColumns = Math.floorDiv((long)(scrollPane.getWidth()- (scrollPane.getWidth() - scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth())), buttonWidth);
                if (columns <= matchColumns) {
                    if(rows * buttonHeight - (long)verticalPadding <= scrollPane.getHeight() - verticalPadding || (rows * columns * buttonHeight ) > controls * buttonHeight )
                    {
                        ancFlow.setPrefHeight(scrollPane.getHeight()-verticalPadding);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ancFlow.setPrefHeight(rows * buttonHeight);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    double matchRows = Math.ceilDiv(controls, (long)matchColumns);
                    ancFlow.setPrefHeight(matchRows * buttonHeight);
                }
            }
        });
        scrollPane.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                if(newValue.longValue() - (newValue.longValue() - scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth()) < buttonWidth) return;
                double verticalPadding = scrollPane.getPadding().getTop() + scrollPane.getPadding().getTop();
                ancFlow.setPrefWidth(newValue.longValue() - (newValue.longValue() - scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth()));
                int controls = flowPane.getChildren().size();
                columns = Math.floorDiv(newValue.longValue() - (long)(newValue.longValue() - scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth()), buttonWidth);
                rows = Math.ceilDiv(controls, (long)columns);
                if(rows * buttonHeight < scrollPane.getHeight())
                {
                    ancFlow.setPrefHeight(scrollPane.getHeight()-verticalPadding);
                }
                else
                {
                    ancFlow.setPrefHeight(rows * buttonHeight);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`HelloApplication.java` file:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        ((HelloController)fxmlLoader.getController()).resizeFlowPaneParent();
        stage.setWidth(stage.getWidth() + 1);
        stage.setHeight(stage.getHeight() + 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

The approach was to wrap the `FlowPane` in a `AnchorPane`. `FlowPane` is anchored in `AnchorPane` to all bounds. The `AnchorPane` is wrapped in `ScrollPane`.

In controller I've created a public method in which I added listners to `widthProperty()` and `heightProperty()` of `ScrollPane` to be able to calculate the rows needed for resizing the `AnchorPane`, based on how many items are in `FlowPane` and how many columns could be made with the `ScrollPane`'s width. This method was added because size of controls must be read after the scene is displayed, which I've done it in `HelloApplication.java` main class. In this way listners are added after all items are displayed, and it will be calculated correctly.

Demo:
[image]

Comment: sry but that's a -1 for hard-coding sizing constraints: whatever the problem, hard-coded constraints are __not__ the solution!

Comment: also: all deeply nested layouts (particularly if one of the collaborators is an AnchorPane) are bound to pose problems, as are bindings to parent sizes. A very quick check: flowPane with horizontal orientation, containing enough nodes (f.i. buttons) as content of a scrollPane with fitToWidth (_not_ fitToHeight), contained in a borderPane, no hard-coded sizing constraints anywhere seem to behave as you want it: comes up with two column (at default scene width), on decreasing width switching to single column and vertical scrollbar

Comment: Probably, but till someone (maybe even you, as long as you downvoted) came with a solution, with exactly how you wrote "minimal reproduction code", I will use something else. Till then, this solution works, and works very well. And, BTW, those nested AnchorPanes are there because contains other controls too, as I said it was extracted from my app :)